# Better way to update UI and strings instead of using recreate() in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I was wondering if there is a better more clean way to recreate my app.
I have a switch that changes the app from `lightmode to darkmode` that uses `recreate()` to change the UI colors, I also use `recreate()` when changing the apps language. However this rebuilds the app and doesn't look that fancy (showing a black screen for a couple of seconds).

Any way to make the transition of changing UI components or text more neat that doesn't rebuild the app?

Comment: do a "fade to black" animation before calling `recreate()` :-)

Comment: Tried using "overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_out)" but didn't do anything.